# url.exists() doesn't return correct value

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to check if the given website exists. However, when I use `url.exists` on this website `http://watermarkcap.com/` or any of this website's pages, I get the output as `FALSE` even though this website exists.

I know I can use `url_success()`, but this function seems to return `TRUE` if the given URL redirects and the redirected URL exists. I need to find if the given URL exists or not, not the redirected URL.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
 library(RCurl)
 webpage <- "http://watermarkcap.com/"
 url.exists(webpage)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I tried your R Script. `url.exists(webpage)` is returning `True` in my RStudio.

Comment: @Ralf17 what version of R are you using? I am using 3.3.1 in Windows.

Comment: I am also using 3.3.1, platform is x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. My operating system is Kubuntu.

Comment: @Ralf17 I tried running this on several windows computer and they all returned `FALSE`. However, when I run on Macbook, they return `TRUE`. They all have v 3.3.1. Not exactly sure what's happening.

Comment: Why don't you install a Virtual Machine in Windows? Have a Mac or Linux OS on your VM and try doing your R stuffs there, if you really want this code to run. I'm not used to Windows so I can't help you in finding the problem there.

Comment: Does the function work for other URLs?

Comment: @Ralf17 yes I will probably do that. Just trying to figure out what the problem is. thanks though. :)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tested this on almost 100 websites and it works for every other URL except this. However, I have to run this on thousands of URLs. Trying to figure out what and where the problem is here.